# Where are the wav files stored in Festival?

Tags: wav, text-to-speech, festival

I am trying to work with `Festival` and trying to synthesize a word with the default diphone based voices that come pre-loaded (`voice_kal_diphone`). I would like to add a few more words in my voice that are currently out-of-dictionary. I am unable to find the directory where the wav files for `voice_kal_diphone` are currently stored. My question(s):

1. Where are the wav files used for synthesizing sentences in `voice_kal_diphone` stored?

Comment: I doubt that they are using pure wav files. They most probably use LPC coded diphones and not entire words.